# Filter columns of a df using other df

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have 2 dataframes (let's call A and B).
In A, I have a structure like this:
[image]

And in B, like this:
[image]

What I am trying to do is to filter the columns name of A that match with B. But I want to keep the first column.

Doing this I get what I want but I lose the Hugo_Symbol column:

```
Data_filter <- A[ ,which((names(A) %in% B$SAMPLE_ID)==TRUE)]
```

[image]

Any help is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Try `df1[names(df1) %in% c(df2$SAMPLE_ID, "Hugo_Symbol")]`. Also please do not share images of data. Use `dput()` to provide reproducible examples

Comment: Try: `A[c(TRUE, names(A)[-1] %in% unique(B$SAMPLE_ID))]`

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick response! Sorry @Sotos I thought it was only one thing missing in my code and I found unnecessary, but you are right, I should put a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Just, add the column name:

```
Data_filter <- A[ , names(A) %in% c(B$SAMPLE_ID, "Hugo_Symbol")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also make and "exclude list" data frame, then use anti_join. This is could if you want to remove based on a number of conditions.

Test/pseudo-data:

```
ID1 <- c(5,10,6)
ID2 <- c(3,5,4)
Value <- rnorm(3)
DF1 <- data.frame(ID1, ID2, Value)

x <- c()
y <- c()
z <- c()

for (i in 1:10){
a <- rep(i, 10)
b <- c(1:10)
c <- rnorm(10)
x <- c(x, a)
y <- c(y, b)
z <- c(z, c)
}

DF2 <- data.frame(x, y, z)
```

Make a 'exclude' list

```
excl <- data.frame(
  x = c(DF1$ID1, DF1$ID2),
  y = c(DF1$ID2, DF1$ID1))
```

Then use anti join:

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(DF2, excl, by = c("x", "y"))
```